# In this HTML file I want to call another HTML file

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

```html
{%extends "layout.html"%}

{%block content%}

<form action="{{ url_for("plot")}}" method="post"> 
<label for="CompanyCode">Stock Symbol:</label> 
<input type="text" id="CompanyCode" name="ccode" placeholder="Stock Symbol">
<label for="start_date">Start Date: </label>
<input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date">
<label for="end_date">End Date:</label>
<input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date">

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Reset</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{cdn_js | safe}}" integrity="sha384-T2yuo9Oe71Cz/I4X9Ac5+gpEa5a8PpJCDlqKYO0CfAuEszu1JrXLl8YugMqYe3sM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class = "plot">
    <h1> This is the plot page </h1>
</div>
</script>
{{script1 | safe}}
{{div1 | safe}}

   1) <div data-include="C:/Users/saiyyam/Stocks_site/Demo/template/plotdata.html"></div>

   2) <div class="xyz">


</div>
{%endblock%}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(class="xyz").load("plotdata.html");
    });    
</script>
```

I have tried using 2 methods but none of them worked would appreciate if you can help me out. The code above the two methods is plotting some graphs so that is no way related to importing files in HTML. And yes i hav used both the methods separately but they didn't work

Comment: use iframe for it in simple HTML page

Comment: ok my answer is ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but not with this setup.. **thank you CORS >:{**

Check out my [repl](https://repl.it/join/kzxaopbv-paultaylor2) for an example since it only loads pages with same [origin](https://CreepyDearInstruction.paultaylor2.repl.co) as it

```js
function htmlLoader(path,element){
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('GET',path,true)
  xhr.send()
  xhr.onload=function(){
    element.innerHTML=xhr.response
    console.log("Page Successfully Loaded from",path)
  }
  xhr.onerror=function(err){console.error("Either due to this being a sandbox(meaning CORS blocked) or the path itself is invalid/rejects returning the call, the request has FAILED")}
}
```

```html
<input id="addPath" />
<button onclick="htmlLoader(document.getElementById('addPath').value,document.getElementById('placeHTML'))">Add HTML from Path</button>
<div id="placeHTML"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just move to a new html page, then using javascript, you can add an onclick attribute to your button `<button onclick="window.location.href='./layout.html'" type="submit">Submit</button>` it might work im not sure just proposing another way :)

Comment: yes but i want it embeded on the same page itself

Comment: for that wont <iframe src="./layout.html"></iframe> work?